# How can i handle this Active Record validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I have three models, `user`, `message` and `message_reply`:

```
#user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :message_replies
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: :sendor_id
  has_many :received_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: :receiver_id
end


#message.rb

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Sendor, class_name: "user", foreign_key: :sendor_id
  belongs_to :Receiver, class_name: "user", foreign_key: :receiver_id
  has_many :message_replies
end

#message_reply.rb

class MessageReply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :message
end
```

I want to validate that the `:user_id` in `MessageReply` is either the `sendor_id` or `receiver_id` of the `Message` instance that this `MessageReply` instance belongs to.

Comment: What is the purpose of `MessageReply` and when is it created? When created, does it already have association to `message`?

Comment: @AbM `MessageReply` is the model for replies to a particular `Message`. It has a 1 to many relationship with message as shown by the models code i've posted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) method and implement the logic in your `MessageReply` class or wherever you see fit.

```
validates :check_user

def check_user
  [custom logic]
end
```